# RREF possible or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to have RREF([A|b]) =
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & * & * & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
Or 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & * & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ 
Or
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I think the answer is no for all the matrices because we should have infinitely many solutions for Ax=b according to cramer's rule but actually there is no solution.

Comment: You can RREF anything, but it might not be nice, or full rank, or diagonal.

Comment: the matrices  you've written are in RREF form, so they are the RREF form of themselves

Comment: @Exodd but is it possible to have matrices which have these matrices as RREF?

Comment: Not every system of equations has infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Check for the following conditions:

- all non-zero rows are above zero rows.
- the pivot of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the pivot of the row above it
- every leading coefficient is $1$.

If we obtain those RREF, it means that we do not have any solution as we have $0=1$.

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$b=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and you obtain such RREF.

remark: apply Cramer's rule only when $A$ is nonsingular.